# IP Address outside of DHCP scope and reservations showing up in WireShark output

Tags: wireshark, dhcp

Wireshark shows all the usual source/destination packet info. Nothing out of the ordinary is showing up for the most part. However, I'm seeing packets sent to my routers MAC address, but there are several packets that are being sent to the MAC address of my router but the associated IP address is not the gateway address. In fact, this anomalous IP address is well outside the DHCP scope and reservations I've assigned. I'm running a CIDR 28 scheme so I've locked down what addresses even can be assigned. For example: 192.168.10.0 through 192.168.10.15 are the allowed scope. All devices with MAC addresses have been assigned something in the range. I'm also allowing for gateway, net ID, broadcast address in this scheme. Then Wireshark shows 192.168.10.235 as a destination IP with my routers MAC address. The routers MAC address is already getting the gateway IP address traffic. What's the extra address doing?

Comment: What's the traffic? Do you know what node is sending it? This is looking like a pure networking question than a security question. If you suspect a security problem, then we would need all the details about what you omitted.

Comment: The source node is another host on the LAN. The packets say TCP protocol. Each packet has a follow up packet indicating [TCP Retransmission]. Thought security since LAN IP address assignments outside of DHCP scope may be a security issue. Thank you, Schroeder, for your attention on this.

Comment: What if a piece of software is hardcoded with that address as a destination?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is perfectly normal. That's simply routing behaving the way it is supposed to.

For any destination address on the directly attached segment hosts will do ARP/neighbor discovery to find the MAC address of the destination host and send the packet to that MAC address.

Any host needing to send packets to a destination address not on a directly attached segment will find a gateway address in the routing table. In most end-user configurations there will be only one such routing entry for the default prefix (i.e. the /0 prefix). More advanced setups may have multiple, but the following steps will be essentially the same in that case as well.

The host will send an ARP/neighbor discovery asking for the gateway address and learn the MAC address of the gateway. The host will then send the packet to the gateway's MAC address and the gateway can route the packet towards its destination.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But why would an IP address outside of DHCP scope be used at all in the ARP? It's the same outside scope address every time I see it. Why not a check of all the other IP addresses. Why just this one. It's the same oddball address every time I use wireshark. That's why I'm wondering if there is a security issue.

Comment: @ArchWeb Addresses outside of your segment are **not** supposed to show up in ARP requests. Packets to addresses outside of your segment will trigger ARP requests for the gateway. And how would I know why you have hosts sending packets to that IP address. You haven't given us any information that can tell us what is going on on individual hosts. But it should be quite easy to find out which host they came from.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the behavior you are seeing is because of setup. If you are trying for a CIDR /28 network, that provides for 14 usable IP addresses, with the x.x.x.15 address being the broadcast address, and the x.x.x.1 address is typically your router/gateway. Thus your DHCP scope should be from x.x.x.2 - x.x.x.14.

Your DHCP server should have complained at the attempt to put the entire x.x.x0 - x.x.x.15 into scope for a CIDR /28 subnet, and I am guessing the reason it accepted it is because the DHCP server is set with the wrong subnet -- it should be 255.255.255.240. That should be the subnet for the routers LAN interface IP setting as well as the subnet the DHCP server hands to clients.

If all this is how you are setup, then the only logical explanation is there is a device on your network assigned the IP address x.x.x.235 statically. Or, you could have another DHCP server on your network -- which happens more frequently than you might imagine.

Comment: Thomas Carlisle, you have described my CIDR scheme precisely. I have mapped every device to a DHCP reserved IP address within the x.x.x.2-x.x.x.14 range. And all of that traffic is accounted for in Wireshark. Here's the kicker: The packets destined for the x.x.x.235 address have the MAC address associated with the router! The Wireshark output shows packets destined for router MAC address and gateway address x.x.x.1 as well as packets destined for the same router MAC address and x.x.x.235. I've pinged that address, nothing there. Tracert returns nothing either.

Comment: Does the router possibly have two ip addresses?

Comment: Just a home network. Nothing fancy. Router settings show proper LAN IP and WAN IP. I have no other DHCP services running anywhere but the router. Would a virtual machine on a host that is part of the DHCP scope cause this?

Comment: The only way a device would get that x.x.x.235 address would be if it is statically assigned or from a DHCP server. What I can't get from your post or comments, what is the exact IP traffic are you seeing that is destined for host x.x.x.235? If you are seeing ARP requests asking WHO HAS x.x.x.235 then that simply means some device on your network is trying to connect to a host at address x.x.x.235. Since that address is not on the local subnet, the router will be asked who has that address. Perfectly normal, but if bothers you then you just have to track down what device is doing this.